# Dhakshinamurthi and Jupiter

Tags: shiva, brihaspati

I know Dhakshinamurthi is a form of Shiva. Jupiter is one of the nine planets(navagraha). But I often find in texts and in the internet these two names are used interchangeably like there is no difference between them. From my understanding Jupiter is Brahaspathi a sage who is a rival of Shukracharya. Is there any relationship between Shiva and the guru (Jupiter ) ?

Comment: I do not know of an instance where they are used interchangeably. You must be mistaken. /That said, propitiating the guru in various forms is recommended for certain results. prayer to dakshinamurti, japas to planet jupiter are two recommended methods for inviting the grace of the guru and can be carried out exclusively or together. this is probably why you see them on the same webpage.  there is also the concept of adhi devata and pratyadhi devata.

Comment: Worshiping Lord Shiva is a remedy for a malefic jupiter.Jupiter is deva guru whereas Shiva(in the form of Dakshinamurthy) is the universal Guru.Thats all i can find.Also, as per Lingashtakam Jupiter is devotee of  Shiva(Sura Guru Sura vara pujita lingam...).I have not seen Dakshinamurthy and Jupiter used interchangeably anywhere.

Answer (score 3):

You might have confused between the words Guru, Brihaspati (Jupiter) and Dakshina Murthy.

There are [many dictionary meanings](https://www.sanskrit-lexicon.uni-koeln.de/scans/awork/apidev/simple-search/v1.0/list-0.2s.html) (clicking on link takes to Monier-Williams Sanskrit-English dictionary) for the word Guru.

The etymological meaning of Guru is as follows (also a popular one):

> **gu**śabdastvandhakāraḥ syāt‌ **ru**śabdastannirodhakaḥ।
>   andhakāranirodhitvāt‌ **guru**rityabhidhīyate॥ 16॥
>
> The syllable gu means darkness, the syllable ru, he who dispels them,
>   Because of the power to dispel darkness, the guru is thus named.  [Advayataraka Upanishad, Verse 16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guru#Darkness_and_light)

#### Relation between Guru and Brihaspati:

Brihaspati is the guru (preceptor, mentor) of devas. He guides the devas during the time of crisis by his wisdom. Apart from this he wrote smritis for the welfare of the mankind He is also called Guru because of this quality. Brihaspati's name is used interchangeably with Guru in texts like Puranas as well (at least 100 references can be found). Thursday is called Brihaspati vasara in Sanskrit and Guru vaara in some languages.

#### Dakshina Murthy as Guru:

In *Dakshina Murthy stotram*, he is called as Guru denoting removing darkness of ignorance.

> nidhaye sarvavidyānāṃ bhiṣaje bhavarogiṇām ।
>   **gurave sarvalokānāṃ** dakṣiṇāmūrtaye namaḥ || [4]
>
> (Salutations to Sri Dakshinamurthy) Who is a receptacle to all Knowledge, Who is a Medicine to all the diseases of Worldly bondage, **Who is a Guru to all the Worlds**; Salutations to Sri Dakshinamurthy. [Dakshina Murthy Stotram](https://greenmesg.org/stotras/shiva/dakshinamurthy_stotram.php)

In the sense of removing ignorance through knowledge, Dakshina murthy is called Guru of all the lokas and *not* as synonymous to Brihaspati, Guru (teacher) of Gods.

Shiva in the form of Dakshina Murthy is called Guru. Besides this, he is the origin of many traditions. He is also called Guru for that reason.  Brihaspati being mentor, teacher to devas is called Guru. Guru also means heavy (Guru = heavy and laghu means light). But Brihaspati or Jupiter is not used interchangeably for Shiva.